# How to store a long hex value message in C++

Tags: c++, hex

I'm learning a crypto class and one of the assignment asked us to xor a bunch of hex ciphertext and try to find the encrypted message.

I know that you can do '0x' in front of int or long to hold a hex value in a variable, but what if my message is this long:

271946f9bbb2aeadec111841a81abc300ecaa01bd8069d5cc91005e9fe4aad6e04d513e96d99de2569bc5e50eeeca709b50a8a987f4264edb6896fb537d0a716132ddc938fb0f836480e06ed0fcd6e9759f40462f9cf57f4564186a2c1778f1543efa270bda5e933421cbe88a4a52222190f471e9bd15f652b653b7071aec59a2705081ffe72651d08f822c9ed6d76e48b63ab15d0208573a7eef027

I would get an overflow. Is there a way to put the whole message into one variable? I could split the message into subparts, but I prefer it to be in variable instead of many (if that is possible). I tried to use string to hold the massage, but how can I use the operator, '^', for xor?

Or is there a more simple technique that I do not know of?

Thanks

Comment: Hex is not different than any integer. Largest integer type is that compilers support is 64-bit at the moment, as far as I know. So you cannot use one integer variable for this.

Answer (score 2):

For something like this, you'd typically use a string or a `vector<char>` to hold the data. You can't use the entire string/vector as an operand to `^`, but you can apply it one byte at a time.

If you want to simplify the rest of the code, you could create a class that overloaded `operator^` to do a byte-wise XOR, so your code would look something like `result = key ^ message;`.

Comment: But how would I input the msg into the vector? From cplusplus.com, I will need to do something like this: 'it = myvector.end();
  it = myvector.insert ( it , msg_byte );', but I would need to store the msg into some variable first. How can I do that?

Comment: If you use a `std::string`, then you could use something like `if (std::cin >> my_string) /* use it */ else /* complain */`.  If you create your own class, you can have an `std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Class_Name& x) { return is >> x.the_string_; }`

Answer (score 1):

You could use an array of, well, any size integer, and apply your operators to it an element at a time (which will probably be a bit more efficient than an array of characters).  @JerryCoffin's idea of wrapping it inside a class w/ an overloaded operator is a good one, regardless of the actual representation you use.

Answer (score 0):

Put it in a separate text file

read the file into a buffer

convert ascii chars to hex values

Answer (score 0):

Jerry & Scott have sound suggestions.  Another option is to use an existing library: for example, the GNU GMP arbitrary-precision maths library at http://gmplib.org, which supports XOR (see http://gmplib.org/manual/Integer-Logic-and-Bit-Fiddling.html#Integer-Logic-and-Bit-Fiddling) and a "scanf" style function to read in hex (see http://gmplib.org/manual/Formatted-Input-Strings.html#Formatted-Input-Strings), and explicitly aims to provide excellent support for cryptography.